# How to trigger GoBack() in WinRT XAML 8.1 WebView control with mouse back button?

Tags: webview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a page in a WinRT XAML 8.1 app that is basically a full-page display made up of a WebView control, in order to display a web page.

For mouse users, it would be handy to be able to use the hardware mouse button that is included on many mice to go back a page in the WebView (not to the previous app page -- to the previous web page).

WinRT 8.1 is nicely programmed out of the box to respond to the hardware mouse back button and go back a page in an app.  But when the mouse is hovered over the WebView control, the app does not respond to the hardware mouse back button at all.  Move the mouse off the WebView, and pressing the hardware mouseback button moves to the previous app page.

SO the question is how do I detect the mouse back button when the mouse is hovering over the WebView control so I can issue a GoBack() command to the WebView control?

Answer (score 1):

Manipulation events and certain mouse events (like these, it appears) are not forwarded through the WebView. There is no satisfactory workaround.

Comment: Well that sucks, but thank you for the response.  The mouse side buttons can't be detected with JavaScript either, so until MS adds this capability to the WebView control, I guess we're SOL.